# Angular Material - Single Dialog with multiple views

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I am trying to create a project where a button opens up a Mat Dialog with multiple Mat Cards that contain an overview of a list of users. Each of these cards has a "View Details" link to navigate to another view/component that will then show that user's details. There will then be a back button to go back to the overall user cards from this screen. I'm stuck trying to figure out what I should be using to make this happen.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

[First view when dialog opens with a list of user cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esWDi.png)

[When "View Details" is clicked from one of the user cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkURQ.png)

It's basically a smaller application within one single dialog, but no routing or tabs involved. One button/link will navigate between the two views/components. I thought about making opening a dialog within a dialog, but that isn't what I wanted after all. I looked into ViewContainerRef but wasn't sure if this is the right direction and was not sure how to call the ViewContainerRef from a child component to trigger the parent component...

Comment: I would just keep a state variable, navigating would just be changing set state, the state could be a simple union string type or an enum. You just have a parent component that deals with the changes of the view.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to Angular. Can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: So when opening a dialog in material, you typically have a dialog component, but that does not stop you from making inner components. So i would just make either the dialog component switch out individual components with basic ngIf or ngSwitch based on your clicks. I would argue making the a component that does that that the dialog can wrap, cause for reusability you could put those in their own page in the future if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the migration tool from the legacy component to the new MDC based ones.

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

Please check the angular documentation

[Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components](https://v15.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration)

Comment: I am using angular material v16+ so I don't think this applies to me?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using Henrik's advice and used an `ng-template` with a bunch of ngIfs, using `@Input` and `@Output`. So it looks like below structure:

html:

```
<div *ngIf="default;else reviewDetails">
   //view here
<div>

<ng-template #reviewDetails>
  <ng-container>
     <app-custom-component [itemDetails]="this.item" (goBackEvent)="goBack()"> 
     </app-custom-component>
  <ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts:

```
goBack() {
  this.default = true;  
}
```

CustomComponent (child component):

```
export class CustomComponent {
  @Input() itemDetails;
  @Output() showDetails = new EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openReviewDetails(): void {
    this.showDetails.emit({item: this.item});
  }
}
```